# Go cannot find package in windows

Tags: go

I have installed a package in windows using

go get github.com/couchbaselabs/go-couchbase

No message apprear after installation.

Then I tried to include in Go

```
    import (
"github.com/couchbaselabs/go-couchbase"
)
```

However,when I build, I got the message

```
main.go:7:2: cannot find package "github.com/couchbaselabs/go-couchbase" in any of:
    c:\go\src\pkg\github.com\couchbaselabs\go-couchbase (from $GOROOT)
    C:\Go\src\Chaatz\src\github.com\couchbaselabs\go-couchbase (from $GOPATH)
    C:\Go\src\github.com\couchbaselabs\go-couchbase
```

Am I miss something, or the package is installed to other path?

Comment: I can't seem to `go get` that package no matter what I try. Ignoring installation with the `-d` flag just creates an empty package with an initialized git repository.

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
>set gopath
GOPATH=C:\gopath
>go get -v github.com/couchbaselabs/go-couchbase
github.com/couchbaselabs/go-couchbase (download)
github.com/couchbase/gomemcached (download)
github.com/couchbaselabs/retriever (download)
github.com/natefinch/npipe (download)
github.com/couchbase/gomemcached
github.com/couchbaselabs/retriever/lockfile
github.com/natefinch/npipe
github.com/couchbaselabs/retriever/logger
github.com/couchbaselabs/retriever/stats
github.com/couchbase/gomemcached/client
github.com/couchbaselabs/go-couchbase
>go version
go version go1.3 windows/amd64
>type cb.go
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "github.com/couchbaselabs/go-couchbase"
)

func main() {
        var _ couchbase.Bucket
        fmt.Println("couchbase")
}
>go run cb.go
couchbase
>
```

Comment: What does `-v` do? I can't find that in the documentation :/ It seems to make the download verbose and logged - but I don't see how that helped you when I tried to get this package at work today on my Windows machine and it didn't like it :/

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: "The build flags are shared by the build, clean, get, install, list, run, and test commands: `-v` print the names of packages as they are compiled [downloaded]." `v` for verbose. [Command go](http://golang.org/cmd/go/).

Comment: Yeah I realised after I said it. Sorry for wasting your time :)